# CDN does not choose closest PoP for blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I have a storage account in South Cental US Data center with images. I have a CDN (Verizon standard) endpoint for this storage account.I am using `SAS` key for accessing my storage account. While accessing contents from CDN, it actually takes more time than getting the data directly from storage account. I investigated and found that the CDN content is being downloaded from US Verizon POP location instead of my closet pop location. I am accessing from India and verizon has a pop location on my city.

Any suggestion what would be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Optimization choices are designed to use best-practice behaviors to improve content delivery performance and better origin offload. Your scenario choices affect performance by modifying configurations for partial caching, object chunking, and the origin failure retry policy.

**This article provides an overview of various optimization features** and when you should use them. For more information on features and limitations, see the respective articles on each individual optimization type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-optimization-overview

Try switching the optimization scenarios, it may resolve the latency issue you are experiencing. let me know if this helped.